# CW structure on $\mathrm{PU}(3)$/Heisenberg group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, cw-complexes, quotient-space

$\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}\DeclareMathOperator\PU{PU}$Consider the quotient space $\PU(3)/H=\SU(3)/G_{81}$ where

- $H$ is the Heisenberg group of order 27
- $G_{81}$ is the No. 9 group of order 81 (see https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/SmallGroup(81,9)) which can be realized as a subgroup of $\SU(3)$, hence acts on $\SU(3)$ via left multiplication.

Namely,
$$G_{81}=\langle a,b,c\mid a^3=b^3=c^9=1,[a,c]=1,[a,b]=c^{-3},[b,c]=a^{-1}\rangle$$
where $a=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&&\\&\zeta_3&\\&&\zeta_3^2\end{array}\right)$,
$b=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}&1&\\&&1\\1&&\end{array}\right)$,
and
$c=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}\zeta_9&&\\&\zeta_9&\\&&\zeta_9^{-2}\end{array}\right)$.

Question: What is the [CW structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex) of the space $\PU(3)/H=\SU(3)/G_{81}$?

(Thank you for your comments/references/answers. Add: The goal is simply to construct a CW structure on SU(3) such that the cells are sent to cells under the group action of G_{81}, so one can further calculate the cohomology of the space SU(3)/G_{81} with twisted coefficients.)

---

Edit:

As some background, one of our goals here is to understand the Schwarz genus of the degree 9 cover $PU(3)/\langle c\rangle\to PU(3)/H$. In particular, we would like to know whether the Schwarz genus is strictly less than the upper bound obtained by dimension. By the general theory of Schwarz genus, it amounts to determining certain obstruction classes in the top cohomology $H^8(PU(3)/H; V^{\otimes8})$ is zero or not. Here $V=\mathbb{Z}^8$ is the reduced homology $\tilde{H}_0(H/\langle c\rangle;\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}^8$, which has a natural action of $H$.

We know the cohomology of $BH$ and $PU(3)$ with trivial coefficients. However, we don't have a clue for the cohomology with local coefficients. We naively thought that it might be possible to calculate it by hand using an explicit CW structure, since we only care about $H^8$. Any comments or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Combination of words "*the* CW structure" feels deeply unsettling, at least for me.

Comment: As Denis T. points out, it is not so clear what you mean by "the" CW structure. You could, for example, try to calculate the cohomology of this space. What you call the Heisenberg group is also called the extraspecial group of order 27. The cohomology of this group is fairly complicated, but is known (Gene Lewis, "The integral cohomology rings of groups of order p^3", TAMS vol 132, 1968). The cohomology of PU(3) is also known. (continued)

Comment: If I really wanted to understand the quotient space, I would try to figure out the homomorphism on cohomology induced by the inclusion, and then try to work out the spectral sequence. I suspect the answer is is unlikely to be very simple or pretty, but it may be doable.

Comment: The goal is simply to construct a CW structure on SU(3) such that the cells are sent to cells under the group action of G_{81}. Thank you!

Comment: But why is that the goal? Do you want to do something with this CW structure or do you want to content yourself with its abstract existence? If the former then there are likely *better approaches which do not use a CW structure*. If you just want to know that it exists then this is much easier than describing one.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! The goal is simply to construct a CW structure on SU(3) such that the cells are sent to cells under the group action of G_{81}, so one can further calculate the cohomology of the space SU(3)/G_{81} with twisted coefficients. Thank you!

Comment: Aha, "...so one can further calculate the cohomology with twisted coefficients" is what both I and Gregory Arone were trying to get to. I do not think a CW structure will help you, because the CW structure on this 8-manifold with $\pi_1 = G_{81}$ is necessarily going to be big and complicated. But Gregory suggests some alternate approaches in terms of spectral sequences which may be doable. If you include in your question which local coefficient systems you want to compute cohomology with respect to, I think it is more plausible you will get an answer.

Comment: Edit 2:  Extra comments are added.  Any comments or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thank you for the added comments, +1. I think you are more likely to get a good answer now. I will try to take a look when I can but unfortunately that is probably not soon.